# How do i pass Object to another activity

Tags: android, json, pojo

I've a class `Testendride`:

```
public Testendride guranteBoneses;
```

set the values on `response`

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
Gson gc = new Gson();
guranteBoneses = gc.fromJson(s, Testendride.class);
```

I'd like to send this `Testendride` object to the next `Activity`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityGuaranteeBonesesOffers.this, ActivityDetailGaurantee.class);
intent.putExtra("gurantee","gurantee");
intent.putExtras("key", guranteBoneses);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Convert Object to String Using GSON 
and then Back it to Object Again in other activity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Comment: how it is possible?

Comment: @Androider it's not duplicate as you think. Anaya Adana make your Object extend Parcelable.

Comment: @Dumbo no its not dublicate

Answer (score 1):

You should make your `Object` implement `Parcelable`.
A short example how to do it:

```
public class MyObject implements Parcelable {

    private final String item1;
    private final String item2;

    public MyObject(String item1, String item2) {
        this.item1 = item1;
        this.item2 = item2;
    }

    public String getItem1() {
        return item1;
    }

    public String getItem2() {
        return item2;
    }

    private MyObject(Parcel in) {
        item1 = in.readString();
        item2 = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<MyObject> CREATOR = new Creator<MyObject>() {
        @Override
        public MyObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MyObject(in);
        }

        @Override
        public MyObject[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyObject[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(item1);
        dest.writeString(item2);
    }
}
```

Then you can use your object like this:

```
MyObject object = new MyObject("first", "second");
intent.putExtra("myObject", object);
```

To get extra use: `intent.getParcelableExtra("myObject");`

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert you `guaranteeBonueses` object to parcelable and pass it to your desired activity. You can read about parcelable in this [codepath  article](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-parcelable)
You can refer following articles too
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-pass-data-between-activities-with-android-parcelable--cms-29559

https://www.101apps.co.za/articles/passing-data-between-activities.html

If you want to pass the network response to your desired activity , prefer to create a new model and pass it , as it is a good practice to seperate your network layer.

Answer (score 0):

I simply do like this

```
Gson gc = new Gson();

            Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityGuaranteeBonesesOffers.this, ActivityDetailGaurantee.class);
            intent.putExtra("gurantee","gurantee");

            intent.putExtra("key", gc.toJson(guranteBoneses));

            startActivity(intent);
```

And received on second Activity As string and then convert it into object class

```
 Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b = getIntent().getExtras();
    Gson gc = new Gson();
    guranteBoneses = gc.fromJson(b.getString("key"), Testendride.class);
```